# What are PIDs used for?

Tags: pid

I know how to get a `PID` of a running process in `Ubuntu`, but aside from killing a running process, what else can the `PID` be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit broad. Maybe it helps to explain what a PID is:

### Meaning of PID

PID = Process ID = Process Identifier

Every process on your system is assigned an unique number. This number is the PID. The PID is only there so that you can specify a process unambiguously. So the question should rather be:

> What operations can be done on processes.

### Operations on Processes

- *Sending signals* (with `kill`). Signals can be used for more than just killing programs, for instance `dd` can output its current progress when sending the `USR1` signal.
- Changing priority (with `renice`). Processes have a priority which determines how much CPU time they get compared to other processes. The priority can be changed by you.